# What is the ground idle fuel flow of an A320 (CFM or IAE or neo)?

Tags: jet-engine, airbus-a320, ground-operations, fuel-consumption

Standing on ground, what is the idle fuel flow of an A320? ISA conditions, both engines running?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t normally post answers that I cannot personally verify, but I have a Facebook friend who is FO in an A320. I sent him a message and asked your question. I don’t have any official documentation to reference, so take this as anecdotal...

An A320 with CFM engines burns about 600lb/hr per engine at idle in ISA conditions.

An A320 with V2500 engines burns about 730lb/hr per engine at idle in ISA conditions.

If the APU is running, it will burn another 300lb/hr.

Comment: I guess that is with the APU running the AC packs?

Comment: @JohnK: That would be my guess. He is based out of Texas, so...